# How to store hierachical data in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to store all makes and models of the cars in my console application.

So I can print them like this:

```
     - Toyota
         Corolla      
         Camry  
         ...

     - Nissan
        Altima  
        Sentra  
        ...
```

So, I assume I need some kind of hierachical data. I was thinkng about making Class Make and Class Model. Make Has a list of models. And Then I have list of Makes. But this looks overly complicated. What is the best solution for this kind of things?

Comment: If you are using sql server backend, and your tables are already created with proper foreign key constraints just pointing a linq to sql file at the structure will automatically create the object hierarchy you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by, "store".  In disk?  In memory for the app?

Databases are good for persistent storage of this kind of thing.  If that seems overkill but you need to store on disk, you could use a CSV or XML file.  If you want it built-in to your app, you could create it programatically, but better to embed a resource and read it into a suitable structure (see below)..

Depending on what you're going to do in your app/program, there are many, many, many, many ways of storing and representing this data.  An object graph (using classes, inheritance etc), a DataSet, a tree,...

Comment: Exactly: The in-memory data model is going to depend on how you want to access it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest in-memory storage that comes to mind is a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, which you populate with a mapping from makes to lists of models. Mind you, this isn't so handy if you want to know what make(s) a given model is associated with, so it's important to understand the common usage patterns before settling on a structure.

If you want to store this in a database, then you'd have to think about a schema, probably something like this:

```
Make  ( MakeName,
        PRIMARY KEY MakeName )

Model ( MakeName,
        ModelName,
        FOREIGN KEY MakeName REFERENCES Make(MakeName),
        PRIMARY KEY (MakeName, ModelName) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on what makes and models mean to your application, if they are just strings, then you can use a dictionary of lists like `dictionary<string,list<string>>` the keys of the dictionary will be the make, and the values are lists of models

Answer (score 0):

```
class CarModel {
    public CarModel(string name){
        CarModelName = name;
        CarSubModels = new IList<CarModel>();
    }

    public string CarModelName {get;set;}
    public IList<CarModel> CarSubModels {get;private set;}
    public void AddSubModel(CarModel car){
        if (car == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("car");
        if (!CarSubModels.Contains(car))
            CarSubModels.Add(car);
    }
    public void RemoveSubModel(CarModel car){
        if (car == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("car");
        if (CarSubModels.Contains(car))
            CarSubModels.Remove(car);
    }

    public void Print(int level=0){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
            sb.Append(' ');
        sb.Append(CarModelName);
        string line = sb.ToString();
        Console.Writeline(line);
        foreach (CarModel car in CarSubModels)
            car.Print(level+1);            
    }

}
```